# ggplot + facet: dropping factors with no data

Tags: r, ggplot2

Let's say I have the following data:

```
z <- structure(list(EVTYPE = c("AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD", "ZZZ", 
"WWW", "AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD", "ZZZ", "WWW"), variable = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("ZOMBIES", 
"PLANTS"), class = "factor"), value = c(354, 765, 389, 321, 438, 
NA, 121, 10, 90, 300, NA, 212)), .Names = c("EVTYPE", "variable", 
"value"), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")
```

And then I plot it like this:

```
ggplot(z, aes(EVTYPE, value, fill = variable)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") + 
    facet_wrap( ~ variable, scales = "free") + 
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, vjust=1))
```

With the following result:

[image: sample plot]

And the question would be: is there any way not to display the empty space for the factor `WWW` on the left and for the factor `ZZZ` on the right (as you see, both got `NAs` in the original dataframe)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with `na.omit` in the following way:

```
ggplot(na.omit(z), aes(EVTYPE, value, fill = variable)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") + 
  facet_wrap( ~ variable, scales = "free") + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, vjust=1))
```

Here's the result:[image]

Hope this helps.